# Prisma Models: can autoincrement() start at 0?

Tags: postgresql, prisma

Is it possible to have `@id @default(autoincrement())` with auto-incrementation starting the `id`s from 0 instead of 1 ?

In relation to : [start ids at an arbitrary number in prisma data model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66415593/start-ids-at-an-arbitrary-number-in-prisma-data-model)
(which did not receive any answer either)

I am interested to see if it is possible with `postgresql` in particular.

Prisma generates the corresponding SQL :

```
CREATE TABLE "Message" (
    "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    "from" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "content" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "discussionId" INTEGER NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT "Message_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

Is the `NOT NULL` the issue ? Would it be ok to remove it ?

That SO answer seems to at least suggest that it would be possible : https://stackoverflow.com/a/32728273/10469162

And if it's possible, is there a reason for Prisma not to expose it ?

Comment: A primary key can never be null, so NOT NULL is required. If you leave it out, the database will (re-)create this constraint anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible from the schema directly but you can modify the migration file to achieve this. This example uses a Postgres database.

Let's assume that we have to start the Task id from 0. To do that, Add the model in schema.prisma file

```
model Task {
  id        Int   @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
  title     String?
}
```

Then run the below command

```
 npx prisma  migrate dev --create-only
```

It will add the migration file in the prisma/migrations folder. Then open the migration.sql file and add the following code

```sql
ALTER SEQUENCE "Task_id_seq" MINVALUE 0 START 0 RESTART 0;
```

Then run the following command to apply in the database

```
 npx prisma  migrate dev
```

Then you should see the output like below
[image: Output you should see]
From here, you can then proceed to create records. For example

```js
const res = await prisma.task.create({
  data: {
    title: "testing",
    updatedAt: new Date()
  }
 })
```

Logging the result to the console, you should see the id starting at 0

```js
{
  id: 0,
  createdAt: 2023-03-09T02:35:53.587Z,
  updatedAt: 2023-03-09T02:35:53.532Z,
  title: 'testing'
}
```

This response was crafted by **ludralph** over at github and reproduced here with him being notified about it for the purpose of sharing knowledge.
Here is the original link of the answer: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/18246

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple options available. The first and preferred is [generated always as identity](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html). Available only in versions 10 and above.

```
create table message (
      id integer generated always as identity 
                 (minvalue 0  start with 0)
    , _from text not null
    , content text not null
    , discussionid integer not null
    , constraint message_pkey primary key (id)
);
```

The other (and required for versions prior to 10) is not define the `id` column as serial, but manually do what serial does. Although `serial` occupies the place of data type in the ddl it is not a data type; it is actually a short for:

1. create a sequence,
2. create column of data type integer,
3. set the sequence as default for column.

So:

```
create sequence message_id_seq
                minvalue 0
                start with 0;
            
create table message (
    id integer default nextval('message_id_seq')
    , _from text not null
    , content text not null
    , discussionid integer not null
    , constraint message_pkey primary key (id)
    );
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/qJCOIT-_). Sorry, but I am unable to translate into your obscurification language (Prisma) as I am not familiar enough with it.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Seeing your answer, I decided to create another question for which your answer is a more direct answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75683301/postgresql-can-a-serial-starts-at-0  Would you like to paste it over there so I green check it ? I have already put a link to here there

Comment: No that just creates a duplicate/answer question. A link is sufficient.

Comment: This question has received an answer on Prisma's github "discussions". While I am waiting for the authorization to post that answer here, here is the link : https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/18246